# How to replace signs in quotes in a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

i have a semicolon separates string, that contains values of every type. string and date values are in quotations.

Now i have an evil string, where an inner string contains s semicolon, that i need to remove (replace by nothing).

eg:

> "Value1";0;"Value2";4711;"Evil; Value";"2015-09-03"

in C#:

```
string value = "\"Value1\";0;\"Value2\";4711;\"Evil; Value\";\"2015-09-03\""
```

So how to replace all semicolons, that are in quotations? can anybody help?

Comment: Hey guys, i cant read an answer there. Please read my post carefully! I DO NOT!! Have a file, i just have a string! So tell me how to do this with the TextFieldParser???

Comment: Thats the correct answer! Open this thread again to post it to anybody else!
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(textBox1.Text);

            foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(builder.ToString(), "\".*?\""))
            {
                if (m.Value.Contains(";"))      // If it contains a semicolon
                {
                    string temp = m.Value.Replace(";", "");
                    builder.Replace(m.Value, temp);
                }
            }

            var parts = builder.ToString().Split(new char[] { ';' });

Answer (score 1):

Regex is **awful** at handling delimited strings. It can do it, but it's not often as good of a choice as it first appears. This is one of several reasons why.

Instead, you should use a dedicated delimited string parser. There are (at least) three built into the .Net framework. The `TextFieldParser` type is one of those, and it will handle this correctly.

Comment: Interesting. Was wondering how I had never seen this class before. I guess it's part of Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll. Hmm...curious.

Comment: It's part of that namespace for compatibility reasons, but it works great from C#.

Comment: It can only handle files, no simple strings!

Comment: Hey guys, you are marking it as duplicate all the time, but you are not answering my question. Show me, how to use the TextFieldPArser with a string! If you can not show me, how can it be a duplucate?

Comment: Older now, but this handles _streams_, not files. You can easily get a stream from a string via the StringReader class.

Answer (score -1):

You should try this i.e to match only those semicolons which is not preceded by `:` :

```
(?<=[^"]);
```

Here is [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cF7fD8/1)

Comment: Where is a semicolon preceded by a colon?

Comment: And the demo does not work well, too

Comment: @ThomasWeller what is the problem , He wanted to replace `;`  inside `"`

Comment: In your demo, the first ; to replace is outside ", the second too